# Simple PhraseQuery can't find any results

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to implement Lucene search on 3 fields in my data. It should work as following:
when the field text is "My big white cat" when I search for "big cat" it would match.

Based on the tutorials I added the `AddToLuceneIndex` method:

```
private static void AddToLuceneIndex(MyObject myObject, IndexWriter writer)
{

    var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", myObject.Id));
    writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);
    var doc = new Document();

    doc.Add(new Field("Field1", myObject.Field1, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("Field2", myObject.Field2, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));       
    doc.Add(new Field("Field3", myObject.Field3, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        (...)
    writer.AddDocument(doc);
}
```

In my Search method i tried to use `PhraseQuery`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<MyObject> Search(string phrase)
    {

        var luceneDir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(LuceneDir));           
        var indexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDir, true);
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);           
        var phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();            
        phraseQuery.Add(new Term("Field1", phrase)); 
        const int maxHits = 1000;           
        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(maxHits, false);
        searcher.Search(phraseQuery, collector);
        var hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
        return MapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher).ToList();
    }
```

There are always 0 hits (although there are matched objects)

When I use BooleanQuery like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<MyObject> Search(string phrase)
    {

        var luceneDir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(LuceneDir));

        var indexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDir, true);
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);  
        var terms = phrase.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
        var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser
            (Version.LUCENE_30,
                new[] { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3"},
                analyzer) { FuzzyMinSim = 0.8f };
        var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        foreach (var term in terms)
        {
            booleanQuery.Add(queryParser.Parse(term.Replace("~", "") + "~"), Occur.MUST);
        }
        const int maxHits = 1000;           
        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(maxHits, false);
        searcher.Search(booleanQuery, collector);
        var hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
        return MapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher).ToList();
    }
```

it works well, but I don't need "big OR cat", I need something I've described earlier. What am I doing wrong using `PhraseQuery`?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with what your `PhraseQuery`.

As stated by @groverboy, you must add separate terms separately to the `PhraseQuery`.  While `Query.toString()` may show the same thing, they are not the same thing.  The toString method does not show term breaks in a `PhraseQuery`.  It tries to represent the query in as close to standard `QueryParser` syntax, which isn't capable of expressing any possible query constructed manually with the `Query` API.  The `PhraseQuery` you've created won't be run through the analyzer, and so won't ever be tokenized.  It will only be looking to the single token "big cat", rather than two adjacent tokens "big" and "cat".

The [explain method](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dd/d6e/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_searcher.html#a508fb2346b1fb8d4d5313304b4fc66fd) provides much more complete information than `toString`, so you may find that to be a useful tool.

Also, you don't appear to want adjacent tokens, either, but rather you need to incorporate some slop into the query.  You want "big cat" to match "big white cat", so you will need to set an adequate level of allowed slop.

So, something like this:

```
    var phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();            
    phraseQuery.Add(new Term("Field1", "big")); 
    phraseQuery.Add(new Term("Field1", "cat"));
    phraseQuery.setSlop(1);
```

---

You could also just run the query through the query parser, if you prefer.  Simply, using the analyzer you've created in your third code block.  You can set the default phrase slop for the query parser, to handle the slop issue discussed.  Something like:

```
queryParser.setPhraseSlop(1)
queryParser.Parse("\"" + phrase + "\"")
// Or maybe just:  queryParser.Parse(phrase);
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the requirement for non-adjacent tokens. And for an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Term` to the `PhraseQuery` for each word in the phrase, like this:

```
var phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();
var words = phrase.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var word in words)
{
    phraseQuery.Add(new Term("Field1", word));
}
```

Comment: I tried but in PhraseQuery there is not difference in passing "big" and "cat" and "big cat". Result is always:
{Field1:"big cat"}

Comment: @KamilBędkowski - Was the `omitTermFreqAndPositions` option set `true` while indexing?

Comment: if you mean something like that:
            doc.Add(new Field("Field1", myObject.Field1, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED){OmitTermFreqAndPositions = true});
i tried with both (true and false) values-still no results